# How to calculate the shape of a curve given y coordinates and slope?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, curves

I apologise in advance if my description of the problem does not use the correct terminology but I'm still learning! Let me know if something is ambiguous or not clear and I'll try to rephrase it.

**The Problem:**

I would like to draw a curve/figure out the shape of a curve given the information in the following graph:

[image]

On the y axis, I'm showing the slope of my curve, and on the x axis I'm showing the height/y-coordinate of each point in my curve. I am missing information about the x-coordinates of my curve.

In this case, because the graph I have shown above is quite simple (a straight line indicating ever increasing slope), I can intuitively understand that my curve will have a shape similar to this:

[image]

However, I don't know exactly how to go about deducing this shape in the case of more complex curves, or even how to go about figuring out the shape of the curve I just showed you in a principled manner.

**Importantly, I am also happy to make the assumption that a slope of 1 equals a change of one unit in the x axis of the graph where I'll draw my curve** (I'm more interested in the shape of the curve, and it's shape relative to other curves deduced using the same method, than in the absolute value of the x axis coordinates).

It just seems like this is the kind of problem that might have already been solved by someone, but I don't really know how to search for the answer since I don't know what keywords to use.

In the example above, the graph telling me information about the curve showed a line y = 2x. However, I might have a graph whose information is not given by a simple mathematical equation (imagine a local regression curve, or a complicated spline).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a linear relationship with $y$. As you have shown in the question the line passes through the origin and has slope $2$.

Therefore,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2y$$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{y} = 2 dx$$

Integrating both sides we get:

$$\log(y) = 2x + c$$

$$\implies y = ke^{2x}$$

The constant $k$ can be determined with some other condition on the relationship between $x$ and $y$.

If let's say it was given that $y(0) = 1$, then our curve would be:

$$y = e^{2x}$$

Your intuition about the shape of the curve was spot-on.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vizag. So just to clarify, the more general solution to this problem would be to do dy/y = [...] and then integrate both sides, correct? What if I didn't have an explicit equation like dy/dx = 2y?

Comment: The problem you had mentioned is called a differential equation. There are many ways to solve it depending on the equation that is given to you. For example: $dy/dx = x+y$ uses a method called integrating factor method and can't be solved with the way I have described in the answer. What is your level of familiarity with Differential equations?

Comment: I see! I should have looked for differential equations! I studied them a long time ago in university so I should probably have a read through them again. So do you know if there is a way to solve a differential equation when the right-hand side is given by a non-parametric curve like a spline or a loess regression curve? (no need to answer in full, if you just point me to where I can find the answer that would be enough)

Comment: Also, the question you have posed in your first comment, do you have the data for the ordered pairs $(dy/dx,y)$?

Comment: yes, I have data for those ordered pairs!

Comment: So if you do, you can calculate the slope and the intercept of the line (given that it is a straight line) or you can find an approximating curve (if it is not a straight line) using Wolfram Alpha or MATLAB. You'll have to search for the ways to do it as I am not familiar with it.

Comment: You can pose the calculation of the curve as a separate question given that my familiarity with that concept is low and people here won't be reading these comments

Comment: ok, thank you very much, will accept the answer and ask another question. Have a great day! :)